# Oracle procedure pagination bringing back more rows than expected

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

This is a shortended down procedure for example purposes. The problem i am have is when i go to the next page on my application it brings back 5, then 10, then 15, then 10. I only want to bring back 5 every time. It appears to happen when the date is descending.

```
procedure GET_DATA( p_sort_col IN VARCHAR2, p_sort_order IN VARCHAR2,
  p_page_index IN NUMBER DEFAULT null,
  p_page_size IN NUMBER DEFAULT null, p_cursor  out l_cursor)
AS
begin
OPEN p_cursor FOR
    select * from (
select* from (select rownum rn, Name, DateCol, ROW_NUMBER() Over( ORDER BY 
 CASE
        WHEN p_sort_col = 'Name' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN
         Name
END ASC,
  CASE 
            WHEN p_sort_col = 'DateCol' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN
           DateCol
     END ASC,
CASE 
        WHEN p_sort_col = 'Name' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN
         Name
     END DESC,
      CASE 
            WHEN p_sort_col = 'DateCol' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN
            DateCol
     END DESC) from gdpr_document_manager_audit  
     ) where  rownum < ((p_page_index * p_page_size) + 1 )         
)WHERE rn >= (((p_page_index-1) * p_page_size));
END GET_DATA;
```

actual query

Comment: Pagination without ordering makes little sense.

Comment: @TheImpaler it has ordering see the order by key words?

Comment: I can only see an `ORDER BY` inside the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. However, it's not affecting the result set ordering.

Comment: @TheImpaler it is actually.

Comment: @TheImpaler when i go the next page in the application it orders the result set first then paginates it, thanks for the input, any actually helpful advice on pagination issue?

Comment: shouldn't rownum be between (p_page_index-1) * p_page_size + 1 and p_page_index * p_page_size . I don't understand why you are dividing.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes typo

Comment: As I commented in your earlier question, your pagination logic is wrong.  If you're going to use `rownum`, you'd need to have an `order by` in your query and be aware that `rownum` is assigned prior to ordering within the same level.  See https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results for a more detailed discussion.  You could also use the newer `OFFSET` `FETCH` syntax if you don't want to use `rownum`.  Either of those will be more efficient than pagination using the `row_number()` analytic function.

Comment: I also assume there is a comma after `DateCol` and before `row_number()` in your `select`.  Otherwise, you should be getting a syntax error.

Comment: @JustinCave can you expand a bit please, what has this to do with the issue i am having?

Comment: @PaulDocks - It looks like you are intending to use `rownum` to do pagination.  If so, 1) your innermost query would need to have an order by.  Your query does not have an order by as @TheImpaler points out.  You just have an analytic function.  2) The general form of the query will need to have three levels of nesting and look like this (from the article) `select * 
  from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
  a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( your_query_goes_here, 
      with order by ) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 
      :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) 
where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;`

Comment: It is possible to use the analytic function to paginate the query.  If you do that, you wouldn't need to reference `rownum` and the query will look simpler.  But it'll be slower.  You can also, assuming a recent version of Oracle, use the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` syntax which should be roughly as fast as the `rownum` approach with roughly the simplicity of the analytic function approach.

Comment: i am using oracle 11g, any chance you could update the actual query above to incoroprate changes, i am getting a bad binding error on etc @JustinCave

Comment: @JustinCave i would prefer to keep it intact, just with the correct pagination logic

Comment: Is the `row_number` analytic function being used for anything other than pagination?  Or can we get rid of it?  If we took the `order by` from the analytic function and assumed that is how you want the results to be ordered, is that fair?

Comment: yes thats what i am after. No its just for pagination

Comment: @JustinCave any joy with that example?

Comment: @PaulDocks - Answered.  FYI, you didn't tag me on the "yes that's what I am after" comment so I didn't see a notification until your subsequent comment.  I also have actual work to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that

```
select event_type, doc_page, application_number, 
       document_reference, username, application_year, 
       full_name, date_and_time
  from gdpr_document_manager_audit
 ORDER BY 
   CASE
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'EventType' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN event_type 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'ApplicationYear' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN application_year 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'ApplicationNumber' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN application_number 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'DocumentReference' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN doument_reference 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'Username' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN username 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'Name' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN full_name 
   END ASC,
   CASE 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'DateAndTime' and p_sort_order = 'asc' THEN date_and_time
   END ASC,
   CASE 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'EventType' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN event_type 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'ApplicationYear' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN application_year 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'ApplicationNumber' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN application_number 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'DocumentReference' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN document_reference 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'Username' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN username 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'Name' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN full_name 
 END DESC,
 CASE 
     WHEN p_sort_col = 'DateAndTime' and p_sort_order = 'desc' THEN date_and_time
 END DESC
```

returns the data you want in the order you want, just without pagination.  I'm going to refer to this query as `#base_query#` in my answer below for simplicity.  If so, and given that you you need to support an older version of Oracle, you'd convert that to a paginated query as

```
select * 
  from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
                a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
           from ( #base_query# ) a 
          where ROWNUM <= ((p_page_index * p_page_size) + p_page_size ) ) 
  where rnum  >= (((p_page_index-1) * p_page_size));
```

using the calculations you have for the minimum and maximum row that you want returned.  You haven't told us what values you are passing for the various parameters.  If we guess that `p_page_index` is 1 for the first page (some people use 0-based indexing), you'd probably actually want

```
select * 
  from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
                a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
           from ( #base_query# ) a 
          where ROWNUM <= (p_page_index * p_page_size) 
  where rnum  >= (p_page_index-1) * p_page_size + 1;
```

So if `p_page_index` = 1 and `p_page_size` = 10, you'd get rows 1 to 10.  If `p_page_index` = 2 and `p_page_size` = 10, you'd get rows 11 to 20.  etc.

Comment: Still have the same problem, the issue is the calculation for pagination. @JustinCave

Comment: @PaulDocks - It looks like you tried to edit my response saying that you got what you wanted.  But then added a comment that you still have a problem.

Comment: yes sorry, wanted to remove the actual query as well. i still have the same problem. the issue is the pagination logic. @JustinCave

Comment: @PaulDocks - I've made some guesses about what values you're passing for the parameters and updated my answer.  If you're using 0-based indexing, that's different.  It may be easier to create local variables for the minimum and maximum row that you can then print out/ inspect to debug.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 etc for page index and 5 for page size everytime @JustinCave

Comment: @PaulDocks - I updated my answer.  Olivier Jacot-Descombes suggested the change to the min and max rows calculation an hour ago but it doesn't look like that is what you wanted.  If you're still not getting the results that you expect, a reproducible test case would be helpful.

Comment: appreciate the help, worked great. @JustinCave

Comment: how do i set a default order by but still allow it to be changed by the application? @JustinCave

Comment: @PaulDocks - I'm not sure I understand the question.  The order in which the procedure returns rows appears to be controlled by a parameter that the application is passing in.  If the application wants the data in a different order, it would need to change the parameter that is passed in.